# Conda openpxyl install results in No module named 'openpyxl'

Tags: python, anaconda, python-import, openpyxl, conda

I installed several conda environments with different Python versions.

After activating my Python 3.5 environment I have installed `openpxyl` via the line given here: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/openpyxl

However, when I try to import I get

> ImportError: No module named 'openpxyl'

When I type `conda list` I do see

> openpyxl                  2.4.7                    py35_0    anaconda

in the list.

(code to import is just `import openpyxl` or `from openpyxl import *`)

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: did you try deleting all openpyxl material  then reinstall it using pip ?

Comment: that did indeed solve it! Thanks!

Comment: good, i'll post this as an answer then for future users who might have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try deleting all openpyxl material then reinstall it using pip.
that's how i solved my problem at least.

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced the Same issue. This might Help you. If we have given python path in the  windows environment variables which is present before we installed anaconda. We can test it by using

```
         python --version
```

It will give you the version if the path is already present as

```
         Python 3.6.5
```

Please remove this path of python which is already mentioned.

Then give the path of the python which is is anaconda directory. Normally it will in the path

```
       C:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda3\
```

Just add this path to environment variables and again check for the python version
that might give you the following result

```
        Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

then it is confirmed that you are using the python which is downloaded using anaconda package manager.
Now you  use the conda modules anywhere.